# Why can't I connect to a wifi hotspot using wpa_supplicant?

Tags: android, wpa-supplicant, wifi-hotspot

I turned on "Wi-Fi hotspot" on an Android phone with mobile service, and why can't I connect to the wifi on my computer? Thanks.

```
$ wpa_passphrase "moto g pure" "mypassword" | sudo wpa_supplicant -D nl80211,wext -i wlp5s0 -c 
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
nl80211: Could not set interface 'p2p-dev-wlp5s0' UP
nl80211: deinit ifname=p2p-dev-wlp5s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
p2p-dev-wlp5s0: Failed to initialize driver interface
P2P: Failed to enable P2P Device interface
wlp5s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (SSID='moto g pure' freq=2437 MHz)
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx reason=1 locally_generated=1
wlp5s0: Trying to associate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (SSID='moto g pure' freq=2437 MHz)
wlp5s0: Associated with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
WPA: No PMK set for PTK derivation
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx reason=1 locally_generated=1
wlp5s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (SSID='moto g pure' freq=2437 MHz)
wlp5s0: Trying to associate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (SSID='moto g pure' freq=2437 MHz)
wlp5s0: Associated with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
wlp5s0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx completed [id=0 id_str=]
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx reason=1 locally_generated=1
wlp5s0: No network configuration found for the current AP
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=c8:a7:0a:b0:a2:06 reason=3 locally_generated=1
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
wlp5s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (SSID='moto g pure' freq=2437 MHz)
wlp5s0: Trying to associate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (SSID='moto g pure' freq=2437 MHz)
wlp5s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (SSID='moto g pure' freq=2437 MHz)
wlp5s0: Trying to associate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (SSID='moto g pure' freq=2437 MHz)
wlp5s0: Associated with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
wlp5s0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx completed [id=0 id_str=]
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx reason=1 locally_generated=1
wlp5s0: No network configuration found for the current AP
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=c8:a7:0a:b0:a2:06 reason=3 locally_generated=1
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
wlp5s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (SSID='moto g pure' freq=2437 MHz)
wlp5s0: Trying to associate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (SSID='moto g pure' freq=2437 MHz)
wlp5s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (SSID='moto g pure' freq=2437 MHz)
wlp5s0: Trying to associate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (SSID='moto g pure' freq=2437 MHz)
wlp5s0: Associated with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
wlp5s0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx completed [id=0 id_str=]
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx reason=1 locally_generated=1
wlp5s0: No network configuration found for the current AP
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=c8:a7:0a:b0:a2:06 reason=3 locally_generated=1
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
wlp5s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (SSID='moto g pure' freq=2437 MHz)
wlp5s0: Trying to associate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (SSID='moto g pure' freq=2437 MHz)
wlp5s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (SSID='moto g pure' freq=2437 MHz)
wlp5s0: Trying to associate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (SSID='moto g pure' freq=2437 MHz)
wlp5s0: Associated with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
wlp5s0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx completed [id=0 id_str=]
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx reason=1 locally_generated=1
wlp5s0: No network configuration found for the current AP
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=c8:a7:0a:b0:a2:06 reason=3 locally_generated=1
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
wlp5s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (SSID='moto g pure' freq=2437 MHz)
wlp5s0: Trying to associate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (SSID='moto g pure' freq=2437 MHz)
wlp5s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (SSID='moto g pure' freq=2437 MHz)
wlp5s0: Trying to associate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (SSID='moto g pure' freq=2437 MHz)
wlp5s0: Associated with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
wlp5s0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx completed [id=0 id_str=]
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx reason=1 locally_generated=1
wlp5s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (SSID='moto g pure' freq=2437 MHz)
wlp5s0: SME: Authentication request to the driver failed
wlp5s0: No network configuration found for the current AP
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=c8:a7:0a:b0:a2:06 reason=3 locally_generated=1
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
wlp5s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (SSID='moto g pure' freq=2437 MHz)
wlp5s0: Trying to associate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (SSID='moto g pure' freq=2437 MHz)
wlp5s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (SSID='moto g pure' freq=2437 MHz)
wlp5s0: Trying to associate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (SSID='moto g pure' freq=2437 MHz)
wlp5s0: Associated with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
wlp5s0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx completed [id=0 id_str=]
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx reason=1 locally_generated=1
wlp5s0: No network configuration found for the current AP
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=c8:a7:0a:b0:a2:06 reason=3 locally_generated=1
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
wlp5s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (SSID='moto g pure' freq=2437 MHz)
wlp5s0: Trying to associate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (SSID='moto g pure' freq=2437 MHz)
wlp5s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (SSID='moto g pure' freq=2437 MHz)
wlp5s0: Trying to associate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (SSID='moto g pure' freq=2437 MHz)
wlp5s0: Associated with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
wlp5s0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx completed [id=0 id_str=]
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx reason=1 locally_generated=1
wlp5s0: No network configuration found for the current AP
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=c8:a7:0a:b0:a2:06 reason=3 locally_generated=1
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
wlp5s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (SSID='moto g pure' freq=2437 MHz)
wlp5s0: Trying to associate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (SSID='moto g pure' freq=2437 MHz)
wlp5s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (SSID='moto g pure' freq=2437 MHz)
wlp5s0: Trying to associate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (SSID='moto g pure' freq=2437 MHz)
wlp5s0: Associated with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
wlp5s0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx completed [id=0 id_str=]
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx reason=1 locally_generated=1
wlp5s0: No network configuration found for the current AP
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=c8:a7:0a:b0:a2:06 reason=3 locally_generated=1
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
wlp5s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (SSID='moto g pure' freq=2437 MHz)
wlp5s0: Trying to associate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (SSID='moto g pure' freq=2437 MHz)
wlp5s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (SSID='moto g pure' freq=2437 MHz)
wlp5s0: Trying to associate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (SSID='moto g pure' freq=2437 MHz)
wlp5s0: Associated with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
wlp5s0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx completed [id=0 id_str=]
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx reason=1 locally_generated=1
wlp5s0: No network configuration found for the current AP
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=c8:a7:0a:b0:a2:06 reason=3 locally_generated=1
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
wlp5s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (SSID='moto g pure' freq=2437 MHz)
wlp5s0: Trying to associate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (SSID='moto g pure' freq=2437 MHz)
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx reason=3 locally_generated=1
nl80211: deinit ifname=wlp5s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING
```

Answer (score 2):

```
nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
```

This suggests you may have multiple network configuration subsystems competing for the control of the wireless interface, [like in this discussion on Arch forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=257352).

If you are planning to use `wpa_supplicant` in stand-alone mode, you should not have other things like NetworkManager or netctl also trying to manage the same interface. Or if you are using just `wpa_supplicant`, ensure that the old `wpa_supplicant` processes from earlier attempts are actually dead before starting another.

If you are using `dhcpcd` as your DHCP client (like Raspberry Pi OS does by default), note that `dhcpcd` can be configured to auto-detect network interfaces and start `wpa_supplicant` automatically for wireless interfaces.

```
nl80211: Could not set interface 'p2p-dev-wlp5s0' UP
nl80211: deinit ifname=p2p-dev-wlp5s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
p2p-dev-wlp5s0: Failed to initialize driver interface
P2P: Failed to enable P2P Device interface
```

Something caused the system to try setting up the interface in p2p mode, i.e. for two WiFi clients to talk directly to each other without the presence of a hotspot/access point.

```
wlp5s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (SSID='moto g pure' freq=2437 MHz)
wlp5s0: Trying to associate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (SSID='moto g pure' freq=2437 MHz)
wlp5s0: Associated with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
wlp5s0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx completed [id=0 id_str=]
```

This indicates that the authenticated connection was successfully established...

```
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx reason=1 locally_generated=1
wlp5s0: No network configuration found for the current AP
```

...but then, your computer decided to disconnect on its own (note that it says the disconnection was locally generated), apparently because it did not know what it should do with that connection. Should it set up a static IP address, or try DHCP, or is this perhaps supposed to be an IPv6-only connection?

The `wpa_passphrase "moto g pure" "mypassword"` produces a minimal `wpa_supplicant.conf` snippet that defines a network SSID and the WPA passphrase for it. But trying to pipe its output to `wpa_supplicant -c` might not work, because the option `-c` expects a *pathname of the configuration file*.

[The suggested command format in the Arch wiki is somewhat different.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/wpa_supplicant#Connecting_with_wpa_passphrase) Try stopping any existing `wpa_supplicant`, `dhcpcd`, `NetworkManager` and/or `netctl` processes, and then running:

```
sudo wpa_supplicant -D nl80211,wext -i wlp5s0 -c <(wpa_passphrase "moto g pure" "mypassword")
```

The `<( ... )` syntax creates a temporary file out of the output of the enclosed command, and substitutes the name of the temporary file in place of the `<( ... )` construct on the command line before executing the main command.